# How do I select just some data from a cell with multiple values?

Tags: excel

I have a CSV file imported into Excel 2010. One cell contains a portion of text that I want, but it is of different lengths and locations within the cell. Not every record has data in the cell. Each piece of text is delimited by a semicolon (;) but still within the same cell. So:

- B2 = **text_I_want**
- B3 = blank
- B4 = text_I_don't_want; **text_I_want_that_has_a_different_length**; more_text_I_don't_want
- B5 = text_I_don't_want; text_I_don't_want; text_I_don't_want; **text_I_want_now**;

Column M of the same row should contain the entire text I want but only what I want. So:

- M2 = text_I_want
- M3 = blank
- M4 = text_I_want_that_has_a_different_length
- M5 = text_I_want_now

There are more than 10,000 records to go through and would appreciate help.

EDIT: I didn't explain myself clearly. Column B contains a string of text which contains various hyperlinks. Each cell could contain zero hyperlinks, one hyperlink, 2, 3, 4 and so on. Each hyperlink is separated by a semicolon. I want only the amazon.com hyperlinks, not the amazon.ca or amazon.co.uk or any other hyperlinks. I hope this is a clearer example, with what I want in a separate field, bolded.
    -B2 = **amazon.com/12345** 
    -B3 =amazon.ca/search?keywords=William+Shatner 
    -B4 =amazon.ca/12AB; **amazon.com/AB1**; loc.gov/fubar
    -B5 =**amazon.com/978037346**; amazon.de/search?VX123
 
EDIT #2 - Since I can convert the text to columns, how about this questions: how do I search a row com columns A-G for any cell containing amazon.com and then copy that cell contents into column M?

Comment: from what i see i think there is a pattern?.. like its moving further away 1 semicolon at a time

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Find/FindB`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/redir/HP005209089.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211) (depending on whether your content is single byte or MBCS data - the ones ending in `B` are for MBCS data).

In `N2`, for instance, you can use

```
=Find(M2, B2)
```

`N2` will contain the offset (index) of the text in `M2` in `B2`, or zero if it's not found.

To extract the text, use [`Mid/MidB`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/redir/HP005209175.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211) and [`Len/LenB`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/redir/HP005209154.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211). You can add this in `P2`, for example:

```
=IF(N2 > 0, MID(B2, N2, LEN(M2)), "")
```

This checks to see if the value in `N2` is greater than zero, and if it is copies the text from `B2` starting at the position indicated in `N2` for the number of characters returned as the length of the text in `M2`. If `N2` is zero, it returns a blank space.

You *could*, in fact, combine both operations into one (it's a little harder to read):

```
=IF(Find(M2, B2) > 0, Mid(B2, Find(M2, B2), Len(M2)), "")
```

Comment: Yes, it does. It appears that the question changed entirely with the edit made after I posted my answer (it's basically a different question than what was initially stated here). It's still pretty unclear what the poster is actually asking, and the garbled text in the edited section doesn't help much. The poster should make an effort to solve this in VBA, and then post *a clear sample*, the code attempted that isn't working, and restate the question more clearly. It doesn't appear that's going to happen, though. My answer still adapts easily to the `EDIT#2` portion though, so I'll leave it.

Comment: @pnuts: Seriously? Trolling in comments on two and three year old posts? You should know better - you're not a new user with 25 rep. Give it a break.  I really don't care if you don't agree with me, so you're proving nothing except that you can act like a child.

Comment: @pnuts: Why do I need to chat? You're being an annoying little troll dropping comments on ancient answers of mine because you don't agree with a close vote I cast. First, I don't need your approval to vote, and second, I don't care if you agree or not. If you keep trolling and being annoying with your comments, I'm going to start flagging them for a moderator. Please stop.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your first edit, with `amazon.com/` in `B1` (for the sake of flexibility) then:

```
=IF(AND(IFERROR(FIND(";",B2,IFERROR(FIND($B$1,B2),"")),"")="",IFERROR(FIND($B$1,B2),"")<>""),B2,IFERROR(MID(B2,IFERROR(FIND($B$1,B2),""),IFERROR(FIND(";",B2,IFERROR(FIND($B$1,B2),"")),"")-IFERROR(FIND($B$1,B2),"")),""))
```

(copied down as required) should work.

[image: SO17689216 example]